# Abstract class with new for Date construtor

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I am new to Java and am trying to apply elements of Java that I recently read such as inheritance, arrays, and  abstract classes.

I have a base class named Person3. I am trying to use the Date class to get the person's birth date.

I am receiving this error:  no suitable constructor found for Date(Date[]) in five places shown below with a comment.

I am researching why this error is occurring and I am not understanding.

Can anyone please explain this error (these errors) in detail? Thank you!

```
public abstract class Person3 extends Object{

    private String [] name;
    private Date [] birthdate;
    private int [] social;

    public Person3()
    {
         for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("INSIDE");
            name[i] = "No name";
        }

        // birthdate = new Date("Jan", 1, 1000);
    for(int i = 0; i < birthdate.length; i++){
        birthdate[i]= new Date ("Jan", 1, 1000);
    }

         //social = 00000000;
    for(int i = 0; i < social.length; i++) {
            social[i] = 00000000;
        }

    }

    /**
     Precondition: Neither theName nor theDate is null.
    */
    public Person3(String [] theName, Date [] theDate, int [] theSocial)
    {
        if (theName == null || theDate == null || theSocial == null)
        {
             System.out.println("Fatal Error creating employee.");
             System.exit(0);
        }
        name = theName;
        birthdate = new Date(theDate); //ERROR
        social = theSocial;
    }

    public Person3(Person3 originalObject)
    {
         name = originalObject.name;
         birthdate = new Date(originalObject.birthdate);  //ERROR
         social = originalObject.social;
    }


    abstract double getPay( );


    public String [] getName( )
    {
        return name;
    }

    public Date [] getbirthDate( )
    {
        return new Date(birthdate); //ERROR
    }

    public int [] getSocial(){
        return social;
    }
    /**
     Precondition newName is not null.
    */
    public void setName(String [] newName)
    {
        if (newName == null)
        {
             System.out.println("Fatal Error setting employee name.");
             System.exit(0);
        }
       else
            name = newName;
    }

    /**
     Precondition newDate is not null.
    */
    public void setBirthDate(Date [] newDate)
    {
        if (newDate == null)
        {
             System.out.println("Fatal Error setting person birthdate.");
             System.exit(0);
        }
        else
            birthDate = new Date(newDate);   //ERROR
    }

    public void setSocial(int [] newSocial){
        if(newSocial == null){
            System.out.println("Fatal Error setting person social.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the Date class?

Comment: @Siddhartha Pretty sure he is using `java.util.Date`. So on that note there is no constructor that will accept Date[]

Comment: Why is `birthdate` an array of dates? How many birthdays do your persons have?

Comment: @Siddhartha I am using java.util.Date

Comment: @Zapl I am trying to see how arrays function in Java for practice. I want to have birthdate array so my Student, Staff and Faculty subclasses can have elements (birthdates) be added.

Comment: @Justin you don't need an array to have different subclasses each with an individual birthday etc. But see for yourself once you're there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date` doesn't have a constructor that takes an array, **but** you do have a `birthdate` field which is a `Date` array. I think you wanted

```
public Person3(String [] theName, Date [] theDate, int [] theSocial)
{
    if (theName == null || theDate == null || theSocial == null)
    {
         System.out.println("Fatal Error creating employee.");
         System.exit(0);
    }
    name = theName;
    birthdate = theDate;
    social = theSocial;
}
```

and

```
public Person3(Person3 originalObject)
{
     name = originalObject.name;
     birthdate = originalObject.birthdate;
     social = originalObject.social;
}
```

and

```
public Date [] getbirthDate( )
{
    return birthdate;
}
```

and

```
public void setBirthDate(Date [] newDate)
{
    if (newDate == null)
    {
         System.out.println("Fatal Error setting person birthdate.");
         System.exit(0);
    }
    else
        birthDate = newDate;
}
```

because `new Date` creates a single `Date` instance; not an array of `Date`(s).

Comment: Thank you! I understand now and worked through your code pieces. I see now that Date with import java.util.Date does not have an array. I appreciate your help, sir.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of Person3 declares an array for thedate. Valid constructors for Date are ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html))

```
public Date(int year, int month, int day)
//Deprecated. 
//instead use the constructor Date(long date)

public Date(long date)
//Constructs a Date object using the given milliseconds time value.
```

Therefore change your constructor

```
Person3(String [] theName, Date theDate, int [] theSocial)
{
    if (theName == null || theDate == null || theSocial == null)
    {
         System.out.println("Fatal Error creating employee.");
         System.exit(0);
    }
    name = theName;
    birthdate = theDate;
    social = theSocial;
}
```

And the birthdate class attribute

```
private Date birthdate;
```

Answer (score 1):

[The accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33202293/642706) by [Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) is correct and excellent. I’ve nothing to add there. Instead I’ll address two tangents.

## java.time

As of Java 8 and later, the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)) supplants the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes.

I especially want to point this out to someone new to Java and just learning [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). The old date-time classes bundled with early versions of Java were a brave attempt at handling date-time, a first for the information technology industry. But in the end they failed. Their faults include some poor OOP design choices. So do *not* look at them as good examples. Better to avoid them entirely, and focus on java.time instead.

## Proper Objects

Your `Person3` class design seems to show that you misunderstand the proper use of a class. A class to represent people means each instance of that class should describe a single person. Then we use collections to gather multiple `Person` objects as "people".

Instead, you seem to have a spreadsheet-like arrangement in your mind. Looks like you are trying to have two-dimensional array listing a person in each row and attributes as columns, then shoe-horning that pseudo-spreadsheet inside an object. That shoe-horning does you no good as you are not take advantage of the benefits of OOP.

Here is a re-worked version to demonstrate OOP design and use of java.time.

While you certainly can use plain arrays in Java (with the `[]` notation), we often make use of the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) classes such as a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) used here. Notice [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) in action where an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is presented as a `List`.

Note that java.time classes generally use static factory methods to instantiate objects rather than `new`. So `LocalDate.of()` rater than `new LocalDate()`. Also note that a time zone is required to determine a date such as "today".

```
package timestuff;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Person {

    private String name;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private String favoriteColor;

    public Person ( String name , LocalDate dateOfBirth , String favoriteColor ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.favoriteColor = favoriteColor;
    }

    public Integer yearsOld () {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneOffset.UTC;
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( zoneId );
        Period age = Period.between ( this.dateOfBirth , today );
        Integer years = age.getYears ();
        return years;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "Person{ " + "name=" + name + " | dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth + " | favoriteColor=" + favoriteColor + " }";
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        Person julie = new Person ( "Julie" , LocalDate.of ( 1954 , 1 , 7 ) , "purple" );
        Person jeanluc = new Person ( "Jean-Luc" , LocalDate.of ( 1965 , 2 , 22 ) , "blue" );
        Person lisa = new Person ( "Lisa" , LocalDate.of ( 1977 , 3 , 18 ) , "green" );

        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<> ();
        people.add ( julie );
        people.add ( jeanluc );
        people.add ( lisa );

        System.out.println ( "people: " + people );
        System.out.println ( "" );  // blank line.

        System.out.println ( "-- Age Report --" );
        for ( Person person : people ) {
            System.out.println ( person.name + " : " + person.yearsOld () );
        }

    }

}
```

When run.

> people: [Person{ name=Julie | dateOfBirth=1954-01-07 | favoriteColor=purple }, Person{ name=Jean-Luc | dateOfBirth=1965-02-22 | favoriteColor=blue }, Person{ name=Lisa | dateOfBirth=1977-03-18 | favoriteColor=green }]
>
> -- Age Report --
>
> Julie : 61
>
> Jean-Luc : 50
>
> Lisa : 38

Comment: I understand the exact purpose of my Person3 class...it gathers information for a single person. I am currently not interested in collections because I want to get the feel of inheritance, arrays and abstract class. Thanks.